# RPY2 - Security issue running on osx-arm64 (M1): Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback()

Tags: python, r

For any one encountering this problem on Mac M1, where rpy2 is not working, try compile from source  while setting `RPY2_CFFI_MODE=API`. If this fails due to some clang compilation errors, you can still use the traditional conda install method `conda install rpy2`. In my case pip3 was not installing all required dependencies. Conda does!

`conda install rpy2`